# Batch file to extract date from txt file

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a text file.

```
AML.DATA|01-JUN-2016
PORT_DATA|560538
NDB_AML_AA|43063
NDB_AML_LD|12878
NDB_AML_REPO|496
NDB_AML_TRAN|84596
NDB_AML_JOINT_AC|219873
NDB_AML_CUS_REL_PRTY|43
NDB_AML_BICCODE|108292
CUSTOMER_MASTER|684124
CATEGORY.MASTER|3288
DEPT.MASTER|2527
COUNTRY.MASTER|251
CUSTOMER.STATUS.MASTER|26
INDUSTRY.MASTER|65
JOB.TITLE.MASTER|22
COMPANY.MASTER|121
TRANSACTION.MASTER|3133
RELATION.MASTER|56
NDB_AML_TBILL_TBOND|2845
EOF
```

I want to extract the date part (01-JUN-2016) from the text file. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? you need to show us your own efforts! You can start with `for /F` -- type `for /?` in a command prompt window and read the help.

Comment: I suppose you will want to calculate a new date with same format but one day earlier?

Answer (score 1):

if the date is always on the first line:

```
@echo off
<file set /p line=
echo "%line%"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%# in ("%line%") do set "_date=%%#"
echo %_date%
```